# Getting error while pip installing paddle for OCR

Tags: python, ocr, paddle-paddle

While running the below command I am getting the below error as popup and few more errors in the CMD. I am not able to understand what is the problem. Please advise.

popup error:

the procedure entry point ?PyWinObject_FromULARGE_INTEGER@@YAPEAU_object@@AEAT_ULARGE_INTEGER@@@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\windows\SYSTEM32\pythoncom37.dll

CMD error:

pip install paddle

Collecting paddle

Using cached paddle-1.0.2.tar.gz (579 kB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

```
 command: 'C:\Users\pearl\Anaconda3\envs\torchgpu\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pearl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g5jav11l\\paddle_bfb737e61a56439f94aa0719d588a1a3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pearl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g5jav11l\\paddle_bfb737e61a56439f94aa0719d588a1a3\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-3p8q8se9'
     cwd: C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5jav11l\paddle_bfb737e61a56439f94aa0719d588a1a3\

Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5jav11l\paddle_bfb737e61a56439f94aa0719d588a1a3\setup.py", line 3, in <module>


    import paddle
  File "C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5jav11l\paddle_bfb737e61a56439f94aa0719d588a1a3\paddle\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import common, dual, tight, data, prox
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
----------------------------------------
```

WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/cf/e4b6b9a54d2f072e4491e34317bf5f5fea260da8a3072e641832dc9ce770/paddle-1.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=aeb13606880a932f97eb1a810bc8820c7e80f943abcdb56f272b1375964ef117 (from https://pypi.org/simple/paddle/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Using cached paddle-1.0.1.tar.gz (539 kB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\pearl\Anaconda3\envs\torchgpu\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5jav11l\paddle_7c0715d6385d491f81a23bc686834c4d\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5jav11l\paddle_7c0715d6385d491f81a23bc686834c4d\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-np03byzg'
cwd: C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5jav11l\paddle_7c0715d6385d491f81a23bc686834c4d
Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5jav11l\paddle_7c0715d6385d491f81a23bc686834c4d\setup.py", line 3, in

```
    import paddle
  File "C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5jav11l\paddle_7c0715d6385d491f81a23bc686834c4d\paddle\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import common, dual, tight
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
----------------------------------------
```

WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/cc/5d3b4eb9c5ea536ddaf10e4d7ec2019e1bde9d0b4207f314f7cf8a1af0d7/paddle-1.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=e4468cfb5be7a2f3373bd93c31541da758027bbd6ffe75f83008a88e70e2eae7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/paddle/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Using cached paddle-1.0.0.tar.gz (539 kB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\pearl\Anaconda3\envs\torchgpu\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5jav11l\paddle_36b2b71c85564f3b8d9e3509e69be391\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5jav11l\paddle_36b2b71c85564f3b8d9e3509e69be391\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-0pfi4b61'

```
     cwd: C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5jav11l\paddle_36b2b71c85564f3b8d9e3509e69be391\
Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5jav11l\paddle_36b2b71c85564f3b8d9e3509e69be391\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    import paddle
  File "C:\Users\pearl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5jav11l\paddle_36b2b71c85564f3b8d9e3509e69be391\paddle\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import common, dual, tight
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
----------------------------------------
```

WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a9/c2/10db468c6a588b208ad22506c0f390059c5fa7a399e2085baefba3dcc24e/paddle-1.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=64abc6b5574da69ea02ca058fbd0677fc0a19473b45c34cf0c4d23aeaf6738e1 (from https://pypi.org/simple/paddle/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement paddle (from versions: 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for paddle

Answer (score 0):

In your case, "Common Module is missing..!".
Try installing "common"

```
pip install common
```

Think this should work..!

Comment: thanks. i installed paddle and it worked